# Can't remove "lang" property with jQuery removeProp()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<p>` tag with a `lang` attribute. I'm using jQuery [removeProperty](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) to remove the property.

```
<p id="jq" lang="en">Hello world!</p>
```

Calling:

```
$('#jq').removeProp('lang');
```

It becomes:

```
<p id="jq" lang="undefined">Hello world!</p>
```

I expect it to be:

```
<p id="jq">Hello world!</p>
```

Also I tried to add the `lang` property with jQuery `prop()`, then tried to remove it, same issue. I believe `lang` is not a native property.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `removeAttr` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is an *attribute* and not a *property*, use [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```
$('#jq').removeAttr('lang');
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I guess 35 years of typing counts for something :)

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye Slow down grandpa

Comment: @r3wt: Grandpa? Not yet? Would you believe I start coding at 1? Nah me neither :>

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye, thanks a lot. Just wondering what is the specific use-case for removeProp() then!

Comment: "The .removeProp() method removes properties set by the .prop() method." https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/ If they are not actual prop values things appear to get a bit screwy :)

Comment: Just a little note to the recent serial downvoter. I have just reported you to SO so they can sort you out. Enjoy :P

Answer (score 1):

Following should work for you: [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)